# In episode 1 of Hyouka, what was the topic of the essay Houtarou has to rewrite?

Tags: hyouka

In episode 1 of Hyouka, Houtarou is forced to stay after school one day to rewrite an essay that he accidentally left at home. What is the essay about?

[image: Hyouka episode 1, Blu-Ray, 16:23 - Houtarou begins writing his essay]

Answer (score 4):

The full title of the essay (partially obscured in the image above) is:

> 「入学一ヶ月の実感と今後の抱負」
>
> "My experiences during the first month of school, and my ambitions for the future"

[image: Hyouka episode 1, Blu-Ray, 18:44 - the second page of Houtarou's essay]

In the essay, he writes about his desire to do his very best to promote culture at his school (via his participation in the classic literature club), adding that this won't interfere with his academic pursuits, as befits a student attending the finest high school in Kamiyama.

Interestingly, when this scene appears in the *Kotenbu* series (on which Hyouka is based), it appears much later, chronologically (in volume **4**), and does not include the text of the essay. His internal monologue in the novel does suggest, however, that he's basically making this up as he goes along to get it over and done with.